# Extracting the value of an element from a JSON

Tags: java, json, getjson

I'm trying to make a test where I get some documents based on the id of the batch they belong to. More specifically, I want to check that a specific batchPublicId is in the response body. I am using okhttp for the test. 
This a shorter version of the json:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "invoices": [
      {
        "type": "INVOICE",
        "publicId": "27bc8426-17cf-4fe5-9278-64108ae05e4b",
        "deliveryStatus": null,
        "processingStatus": "INITIATED",
        "batchPublicId": "0000000000000000000000001"
      }
     ]
   }
}
```

I'm new to json and this is how far I got with the problem:

```
String invoicesJsonData = response.body().string();
JSONObject invoicesJsonObject = new JSONObject(invoicesJsonData);

Assert.assertTrue(invoicesJsonObject.getJSONObject("_embedded") !=null && invoicesJsonObject.getJSONObject("_embedded").has("invoices"));
```

I would like to verify that batchPublicId has the value mentioned in the json. Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: try with my answer below.

Comment: See my updated answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
String invoicesJsonData = response.body().string();
JSONObject invoicesJsonObject = new JSONObject(invoicesJsonData);
JSONObject invoicesJsonObject1 = invoicesJsonObject.getJSONObject("_embedded");
JSONArray f2=invoicesJsonObject1.getJSONArray("invoices");
 for(int i=0;i<f2.length();i++){

          JSONObject obj=f2.getJSONObject(i);
         if(obj.get("batchPublicId")!=null){
             System.out.println(obj.get("batchPublicId"));
         }
```

Comment: @H.Avram but above solution is not a standard  why to find key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,Which worked out for me sometimes back.

```
String invoicesJsonData = response.body().string();
JSONObject invoicesJsonObject = new JSONObject(invoicesJsonData);       

JSONObject invoicesJsonObject = json.getJSONObject("invoicesJsonObject");
String batchPublicId = invoicesJsonObject.getString("batchPublicId");
System.out.println( "batchPublicId: " + batchPublicId );
if(batchPublicId !=null){
// do something
}
```

Not sure about the syntax.Giving you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

you can check any keys is there in `json` object or not like below :

```
  if(jsonObject1.has("batchPublicId")){
  String batchPublicId = jsonObject1.optString("batchPublicId");
  Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "batchPublicId=" + batchPublicId);}
```

`has` method is used to find any key is there in `jsonobject` or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a better approach for this would be to create a POJO from this JSON string, and extract the information you need using simply the getters

For example:

Wrapper class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName(value = "_embedded")
public class Embeded {

  @JsonProperty("invoices")
  private List<Invoice> invoices;

  public Embeded() {}

  public List<Invoice> getInvoices() {
    return invoices;
  }

  public void setInvoices(List<Invoice> invoices) {
    this.invoices = invoices;
  }
}
```

Invoice class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Invoice {

  @JsonProperty("type")
  private String type;
  @JsonProperty("publicId")
  private String publicId;
  @JsonProperty("deliveryStatus")
  private String deliveryStatus;
  @JsonProperty("processingStatus")
  private String processingStatus;
  @JsonProperty("batchPublicId")
  private String batchPublicId; 

  public Invoice() {}

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getPublicId() {
    return publicId;
  }

  public void setPublicId(String publicId) {
    this.publicId = publicId;
  }

  public String getDeliveryStatus() {
    return deliveryStatus;
  }

  public void setDeliveryStatus(String deliveryStatus) {
    this.deliveryStatus = deliveryStatus;
  }

  public String getProcessingStatus() {
    return processingStatus;
  }

  public void setProcessingStatus(String processingStatus) {
    this.processingStatus = processingStatus;
  }

  public String getBatchPublicId() {
    return batchPublicId;
  }

  public void setBatchPublicId(String batchPublicId) {
    this.batchPublicId = batchPublicId;
  }
}
```

Test:

```
  public void json_test() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    String json = "{"
            +  "\"_embedded\": {"
            +    "\"invoices\": ["
            +    "{"
            +    "\"type\": \"INVOICE\","
            +   "\"publicId\": \"27bc8426-17cf-4fe5-9278-64108ae05e4b\","
            +  "\"deliveryStatus\": null,"
            +  "\"processingStatus\": \"INITIATED\","
            +  "\"batchPublicId\": \"0000000000000000000000001\""
            +   "}"
            +  "]"
            + "}"
            + "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    List<Invoice> invoices = mapper.readValue(json, Embeded.class).getInvoices();
    Assert.assertTrue(StringUtils.equals(invoices.get(0).getBatchPublicId(), "0000000000000000000000001"));
  }
```

Comment: Parts of this solution are helpful but I test endpoints, so I will not really ever use a String json in a test.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your right, you just need to call:
`Assert.assertTrue(invoicesJsonObject.getString("batchPublicId").equals("0000000000000000000000001"));"`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a test for JSON Validation, you can use the JSONAssert.

JSONAsset give the method assertEquals, that compare two json structures, strict identic or not.

```
final String expected_result = YOUR_EXPECTED_RESULT;
JSONAssert.assertEquals(YOUR_EXPECTED_JSON_RESULT, RESULT_FROM_RESPONSE_BODY, false);
```

The last boolean parameter defines if you want an strict comparation or just compare if your expected result is in result from response.